# Is it okay to add something non-TLD non-hostname as a host alias?

Tags: linux, alias, hosts

I added some custom (non-TLD) aliases to my /etc/hosts to get rid of IP addresses in my services configuration files.

Are there any caveats/gotchas/security implications i should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, adding convenience entries to `/etc/hosts` won't cause any problems *per se*, but you may find yourself momentarily stymied when you move to another host (e. g. via `ssh`) and your shortcuts do not work.   It's possible some oddball applications will eschew the system call for DNS resolution and do it "by hand" so to speak, and if poorly written or designed might skip checking `/etc/hosts`, but I suspect these are few and far between.